# Realm returns object with empty RLMArray as property

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have class `Country`. It's a simple subclass of RLMObject. Basically when I'm saving `Country` then they do have `regions` (property of type RLMArray containing several object of type Region. Which are RLMObject subclass) but when I'm fetching it from Realm then `regions` are nil.

I've double check realm with browser and those data are there. Maybe I'm using wrong technique to fetch those data?

At this point I use realm-objc because I have to support devices with

**Country** (27 lines)

```
public class Country: RLMObject {
   public dynamic var name = ""
   public dynamic var desc = ""
    public dynamic var id = 0
    public var regions = RLMArray(objectClassName: Region.className())
    override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    override init!() {
        super.init()
    }

    public func configure(id:Int,json:JSON){
        self.name = json["name"].stringValue
        if let desc = json["desc"].string {
            self.desc = desc
        }
        for (key:String, value:JSON) in json["regions"] {
            let region = Region()
            region.configure(key.toInt()!,json:value)
            self.regions.addObject(region)

        }
        self.id = json["id"].intValue
    }
}
```

**CountryManager** (36 lines)

```
public class CountryManager: NSObject {

    public func saveWines(json:JSON) {
        var countriesForStore = [Country]()
        let db = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
        for (key:String, subJson:JSON) in json{
            let country = Country() //Serialize each country
            country.configure(key.toInt()!,json:subJson)
            countriesForStore.append(country)
        }

        db.beginWriteTransaction()
        db.addOrUpdateObjectsFromArray(countriesForStore)
        db.commitWriteTransaction()
    }

    public func regionsForCountryWithNameLike(name:String) -> RLMResults {
        let db = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
        let countryPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[c] %@", name)
        let countries = Country.objectsWithPredicate(countryPredicate)

        var rawRegionNames = [String]()
        for country in countries {
            if let c = country as? Country {
                for region in c.regions{
                    rawRegionNames.append((region as! Region).name)
                }
            }

        }
        let regionNames = "','".join(rawRegionNames)
        let regionPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name IN {'\(regionNames)'}")
        let regions = Region.objectsInRealm(db, withPredicate: regionPredicate)
        return regions
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `public var regions` to be `dynamic public var regions`, since Realm requires `RLMArray` properties to be dynamic.